# What GPL license to use on a Linux distro

Tags: licensing, gpl, license-compatibility, linux-distribution

What license should we use on a new linux distribution? I'm new in licensing and this really confuses me.

Most "direct" programs, like desktop and the kernel itself, are licensed under GPLv2 but other stuff mostly plymouth themes and themes are licensed under GPLv3. So what license do we have to use? I read the entire day on what license to use, first we wanted to use GPLv2 then GPLv2+ now were at the point of saying GPLv3.

To sum up this really confuses me as i think I'm primarily not understanding the seperation.

So what license would you use?

Edit: it may get even complexer when i look at the mit software that is going to be preinstalled and the one theme that uses CC-BY-SA-4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Linux distribution does not have "a license". It is an aggregation, and contains multiple components, each of which have their own license.